# Dudas con el prefijo del selector en Angular

Tags: angularjs-2.0

El prefijo de los selectores en Angular por defecto es 'app'. La mayoría de los ejemplos y tutoriales que he visto no siguen la norma del prefijo. No es un problema mayor porque aunque no se use el prefijo la aplicación funciona, aunque entiendo que no es una buena práctica.

Mi duda surge en el momento que creo módulos. ¿Puedo utilizar un prefijo diferente? Entiendo que la idea de hacer un módulo es encapsular una funcionalidad, así que me parece lógico que tenga un prefijo diferente.

Editado para que se vea muestra de código con lo que me refiero al prefijo de selector.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-animals',
   templateUrl: './animals.component.html',
   ...
})
```

Comment: Hola Quidi. has mirado la documentacion de Angular al respecto para saber si se puede? Has intentado algo ? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Si que he mirado la documentación y por Google y no digo que esa información no exista, pero mi inglés es bastante limitado y en español el tema no se aborda...

Comment: Cuando dices prefijo del selector, te refieres a la directiva ng-app? Puedes dar un ejemplo de donde no se utilizar el prefijo que indicas o por lo menos el link?

Answer (score 2):

Usar un prefijo puede ayudar a reconocer, cuando estás mirando o editando plantillas (templates), los tags que son de tu aplicación de los nativos de html o de alguna otra librería que estés usando, pero tú puedes elegir cuál quieres usar (o no usar ninguno).

Cuando usas [angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) para generar nuevos componentes, siempre usa por defecto el prefijo 'app-', pero esto es configurable si editas `angular-cli.json` y modificas el valor de `"prefix"`.